# Intersection a vector and a nth row of a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab

I am looking to speed up my MATLAB code by removing some loops so I would like to get assistance in finding an alternative, faster execution time, solution. The following is what I am trying to achieve within a bigger loop:

```
for i=1:some_number

%Matrix 1
mat1=randi([0,1],10,10);

%Comparison vector. This is generated every some_number but for this 
%itteration lets have it as 
vec=[3,4,6,7,8];

%The rest is pseudo code and what I need help with

find all the indexes of mat1 that are 1 on a row by row case so the result 
should be row_dimension of mat1 deep with variable coloumns per row 

find intersection of the above resultant matrix and vec on a row by row 
basis so there should be row_dimension of mat1 number of intersections
```

I did try some code but I think its going to be slow, and its not working at a certain point, so I am looking for help with finding a better way to do what I am after

```
mat1=randi([0,1],10,10);
vec=[3,4,6,7,8];
[rows,cols]=size(mat1);
temp1=nan(rows,cols);
for i=1:1:rows
   temp1(i,:)=find(mat1(i,:)==1); %This doesn't work
end
temp2=intersect(vec,temp1,'rows'); %I don't know if this would work as I 
can't get temp1 to work
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't understand your pseudocode.  Can you give an example of your intended output for some particular value of `mat1`?

Comment: Smaller example:
mat1=[0,1,0;1,0,0;0,1,1];
mat1indexesof1s=find where there are 1s in mat1 so result would be something like: resultant=[2;1;2,3]
vec=[2];
intersections of resultant and vec would return something like: final_matrix=[2,empty,2]
This tells me that, based on my vector, there is a 1 at position 2 in row 1 and position 2 at row 3.
If the vec was vec=[2,3]; then final_matrix would be final_matrix=[2;empty;2,3]
I hope that makes it clearer

Comment: It also may be worth adding that in a case where vec=[4]; final_matrix=[empty;empty;empty]; So I am trying to find intersections of the index values stored in vec and a specified state of data in mat1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that occurs to me is to do something like this:

First, convert `[3 4 6 7 8]` into the vector

`v = [ 0 0 3 4 0 6 7 8 0 0 ]`

where the *i*-th index is *i* if *i* is in `vec`, or 0 otherwise.

Now, suppose `mat1` is something like

```
   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1
   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

if we take the elementwise product, `mat1 .* v`, we get

```
   0   0   3   4   0   6   7   8   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   6   7   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   4   0   6   7   0   0   0
   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   3   0   0   0   7   0   0   0
   0   0   3   4   0   0   0   8   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0   0   0
   0   0   3   0   0   6   7   0   0   0
   0   0   3   4   0   0   0   8   0   0
```

Then we just need to drop the zeroes.  I have Octave here which apparently doesn't have `rowfun`, but I think something like this should work in MATLAB:

```
 rowfun(@(w) w(find(w != 0)), mat1 .* v)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that may do it. I get an error with rowfun(@(w) w(find(w ~= 0)), mat1 .* v)
Undefined function 'rowfun' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'. I can ignore the 0s.

Comment: According to the documentation it's been in MATLAB since 2013b:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rowfun.html

 but since I don't have MATLAB here I don't have any way to test it.  Of course you could just write your own method to strip out the zeroes.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions on how to convert the v=[ 3 4 6 7 8] to the padded with 0s form? I would only know how to do it with a loop and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: In this case the 0s can be  left in place as they don't occur in the data set and will never be considered in further processing. This solution has been a massive step forward.

Comment: `v = zeros(1, 10)` followed by `v(vec) = vec` is one option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clc; clear;
%mat1=[0,1,0;1,0,0;0,1,1];
%vec=[2];
%%data input
mat1=randi([0,1],10,10);
vec=[3,4,6,7,8];
%find the indexes of 1s
[x,y]=find(mat1==1);
%find the postion of 1s 
%that are not in vec 
ind=~ismember(y,vec);
%delete them
x(ind)=[]; y(ind)=[];
%gather the answers
for ii=1:size(mat1,2)
  A{ii}=y(find(x==ii));
end;
A
```

Comment: Thank you. So the for loop needs to use cell arrays? I was trying to avoid that as the next step of processing becomes trickier. Would you know if there is any way to do this without for loops as my actual data is much larger than 10 rows.

Comment: But the length of every row are not equal, [2, empty 2] is actually not a vector but a cell array in my point of view.

Comment: Or maybe just delete the 1s in `mat1` that doesn't belong to a row which is a member of `vec`, and find the indexes of them in next step? Then the @DanielMcLaury 's idea, something like `mat1.*vec`, fits the problem better.